# Changing the root_dir on a magento system

Tags: magento, migration, development-environment

I want to create another instance of magento for development purposes.

I've copied the site and the database and changed the connction string for the database.

However, when I go to log in to magento it re-directs to the live site www.example.com rather than going to the test url test.example.com.

Both instances exist on the same box.

After a bit of digging arund I think I need to change the root_dir, but not sure where to change this.

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Tom

-- Edit --

I've updated the two fields in question in the database, but all urls still point to the production environment.

Do I have to run a specific script to update all of these across the whole site?

-- Edit 2 --

There was more than one instance of the two urls in the table, after updating these and deleting the cache and sessions directories from the var folder everything worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the database table "core_config_data". Look for records with a path of "web/secure/base_url" or "web/unsecure/base_url" and you will see where to change the URL. You may need to clear the cache.
You don't need to change root_dir after all since that is automatic.

Comment: You also need to make sure that you execute `./pear mage-setup` from the new location to reset the paths for `downloader` otherwise you'll overwrite modules in your old (production!) instance next time you use Magento Connect!!  To be really safe, delete the .ini files from inside `downloader` before running `mage-setup`

Comment: To remove the risk of damaging anything on the production site I have created a local copy of the site. At present the only environment I have is  windows server running xampp. i have managed to get the site setup and working, but still suffering the same re-direct issue. How would I run the `./pear mage-setup` under windows?

Comment: I managed to fix this. There was more than one instance of `web/unsecure/base_url`and `web/secure/base_url` I changed all options and deleted the cache and sessions folders from the var directory. It then started working.